# Transaction Pending and Dropped

Tags: transactions, cpp-ethereum, nonce

I have a transaction pending from 4 days.
I have tried to unlock following this answer:
[MyEtherWallet is pending and dropping. It looks like it is stuck in a loop for 2 days?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32917/myetherwallet-is-pending-and-dropping-it-looks-like-it-is-stuck-in-a-loop-for-2)

Now the current nonce is 34, but the pending tx has nonce 27.

If I try to resend the tx with Higher GAS, the new tx fails with the error "nonce too low"

How can I unlock/resend tx?

Answer (score 0):

If current nonce is 34 then nonce 27 was already mined (nonce is incremented by 1 from 0 and cannot be repeated).

A transaction with a lower nonce than the last mined transaction will never be accepted and will be dropped immediately from the network.

Comment: but tx with nonce 27 still pending and dropped

Comment: Do you have the tx hash? If 27 was not mined yet then 34 cannot be the last mined nonce. Are you perhaps mixing different networks?

Comment: 0xc7214fd9ea7f568e4606724a7227569304f5a862ecd7ecebace6f5b491183858

Comment: If you look at etherscan it say it was dropped, the mined tx with nonce 27 is 0x7c5124118f8b80b7d1a512eaa5a4d3a46cf2a05759354028bdbd18a0dd93867d.

Comment: ok, but now the amount of dropped tx is not on my wallet and not arrived to destination. how can unlock it?

Comment: The value transfered in that transaction was never removed from your wallet. If your wallet shows a different value than etherscan you should contact with the wallet support so they can refresh/update the balance.